# Подписка Android клиента на уведомления от сервера

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Есть Android приложение. Работает с сервером через REST API. 
Несколько раз в день сервер получает извне информацию, которую надо разослать клиентам. Как это реализовать помимо двух методов ниже, которые мне не очень подходят:

- клиент через определенные промежутки времени будет запрашивать сервер
  о наличии информации
- организовать постоянное общение с сервером через WebSocket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это возможно сделать только 2 перечисленными вами способами.

Лучше всего использовать 2 способ в реализации `FirebaseCloudMessages`. Выглядеть будет так:

1. Приложение подписывается на `topic` через либу `Firebase`
2. Сервер получил данные и шлёт сообщение об этом в топик через либу `Firebase`.
3. Либа отправляет запрос на сервера `Firebase`
4. Сервера `Firebase` постоянно соединены с телефонами посредством приложения `GooglePlayServices`, которое есть почти на каждом телефоне. Через это соединение они отправляют вашу информацию на все девайсы, подписанные на топик.
5. В момент прихода сообщения на девайс будет вызван переопределённый вами библиотечный метод в котором будет информация от сервера.

Такая реализация избавляет вас от переодического похода в сеть своими силами и нужды реализовывать самостоятельно поддержание постоянного соединения с сервером, что на новых версиях андроида сделать безболезненно для юзера и программиста невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо! Неплохое решение!

Comment: Возможно отправлять уведомления определенным android устройствам, например, идентифицируя их через ANDROID_ID?

Comment: @Danilka37, возможно. Либа сама генерит ID и вы можете его на сервер передать и отправлять сообщения определённому девайсу.